# Which is the Efficient way to add 'top property' to the existing top for all the elements under the selected element in CSS or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container full of absolutely positioned divs. I want to display the set of absolutely positioned divs one below another with a constant top value 40px. So when I create the divs from JSON I'm incrementing top value to all the elements.

```
    let topVal = 0

    function fetchItem(data) {
        title = data.title;
        el = document.createElement("div");
        el.className = "row";
        el.innerHTML = `${title}`;
        el.style.top = topVal + "px";
        topVal += 40;
        container.appendChild(el);
    }
```

Now the problem is, when I select any row, I should create a new child element under the selected row and I have to adjust the top of all the elements below that.So I'm adding the top to all the elements below like this

```
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;
    target.setAttribute("class", "row active");
    let newEl = document.createElement("div");
    newEl.className = "expand-box";
    target.appendChild(newEl);
    appendTopToNextSiblings()
}, false);

function appendTopToNextSiblings() {
    var list;
    list = document.querySelectorAll(".row.active ~ div");
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
        let temp = parseInt(list[i].style.top) + 50 + "px";
        list[i].style.top = temp;

    }
}
```

I'm handling this for only 1 click right now.

I cannot modify the absolute position of these divs. Is there any better way to add top to all these elements or any other better way to handle this situation? I want to achieve this in pure javascript or CSS.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

I have attached the fiddle link here https://jsfiddle.net/ytebvazj/2/

Comment: divs in the your fiddle dont need to be absolutely positioned to achieve where you want them.  is there a particular reason why you must have them absolutely positioned?  just trying to see if you can save yourself a bunch of unnecessary dynamic position calculations

Comment: @user3366943 yeah I cannot modify that part of the code !

Comment: what do you mean? the code you have calls fetchItem(data) to create the divs in your fiddle. can you give me more information about the build? how does your event listener even work in the context of the divs? how do the divs get into your build at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

try margin-top:10px

```
.expand-box {
height: 50px;
margin-top: 10px;
background: paleturquoise;
width: 80%;
border: 1px solid grey;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;}
```